# Octave: How to load grayscale images in double format?

Tags: octave

I am using the imread function in Octave to load an image:

```
image = imread ("data/images/image1.jpg")(:);
```

This is apparently loading the image as a matrix of integers with values 0-255.

I want to load it as matrix of doubles with values 0.0-1.0.  I can convert it like this.

```
doubleImage = double(image) / 255.0;
```

However, converting it is pretty slow, especially for a lot of images.  Is there any way to load the image directly as a matrix of doubles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to directly read it as doubles. It doesn't make sense anyway, because the image is an integer in the file, so integers will always have to be read first.  If a conversion into another type is to be done, it makes sense that it does done separated.  Or maybe, use a file format that stores images in double floating point precision.

However, there is a better way to do what you are doing to convert into a double.

```
pkg load image;
img = imread ("image1.jpg");
img = im2double (img);
```

Using `im2double` won't make it faster (the operation it performs is the same as yours) but it will save you if in the future the image that is read is `uint16`, and even if the image already is of class double.

Also, I don't see how the conversion to double is slow. This a really fast operation.

Comment: By slow I meant it takes longer to convert the image to double than it does to load the image.  Even slower because I still have to do both.  Loading the image as a double would be more efficient.

Comment: @Mouscellaneous even if `imread` had an option to do it, it wouldn't be much faster. It would still need to read an integer, then cast it to double, and then divide by 255. About the slowness that you are experiencing, you should check what is the slow part: the cast to double, or the division by 255.